# Removing a file from versioning but keeping it locally?

Tags: mercurial

What is the hg command for removing a file from versioning but keeping it locally? I can do `hg remove` but that will also remove the file locally. It's the SDK files that I don't want to version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `hg forget`.