# Amending .gitignore, removing files from git while keeping them locally

Tags: git, gitignore

All of the developers have files which should have been in .gitignore from the start of the project, but which were not.

Is there a git command to remove files from git, while keeping them locally **and** keeping them locally on all the other developer machines, when they `git pull`?

Ideally this should look at a diff of .gitignore to decide what needs to be removed but kept locally.

At the moment, I am considering the following manual procedure:

My Machine:

1. get full paths of all files which match the new `.gitignore`, but which don't match the old `.gitignore`
2. add all of those files to an out-of-tree tar file
3. `git rm` all those files
4. `commit` and `push origin master` the changes
5. email the tar file to all the other developers

Every other developer's machine:

1. `git pull` which will update `.gitignore` and *remove* their local copies of the files which should now be ignored.
2. untar the tar file over the top of the local repo to reinstate the removed files

**This procedure has huge scope for manual errors - is there a better way?**

I've looked at:

[Remove file from Git without deleting them locally and remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32887956/remove-file-from-git-without-deleting-them-locally-and-remotely)

[Removing a file from versioning but keeping it locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674732/removing-a-file-from-versioning-but-keeping-it-locally) and

http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html

Comment: I believe you could only tell the developer to copy the files and then pull. Had a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Locally you can do this by:

`git rm --cached FILE_NAME`

Arlo Carreon explains how to do this for multiple developers: http://www.arlocarreon.com/blog/git/untrack-files-in-git-repos-without-deleting-them/